# Please identify the typeface in the Atlas Lighting Products logo

Tags: font-identification

[image]

What is the font in this logo? I have searched Dafont and other sources, but all I could find was the Convoy typface. Convoy has no lowercase glyphs, though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Best match for this will be [**Revue**](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Revue/)

[image]

Hope this helps